# How to target buttons to add a new paragraph field

Tags: forms, paragraphs

In a form_alter hook I'm trying to target the buttons to add a new paragraph but can't seem to target the specific buttons.  The buttons are multiple entity references with unlimited cardinality, but for my use case I would like for once one entity is chosen, only that entity can be chosen again in the repeater, which is why I'm trying to disable the other buttons. I want to allow unlimited cardinality but only one paragraph type to be chosen at a time.
This works to unset the entire row of buttons...

```
$form['field_select_card_type']['widget']['add_more']
```

But this does not work to target the specific button...

```
$form['field_select_card_type']['widget']['add_more']['add_more_button_grey_card_w_image']
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, where, and how. In a form alter hook you try to target a button. To add a new paragraph. I don't get the connection. Can you please add more detailed info? 

Comment: Yes, in a form alter hook, I've updated my question.